# Two struct `vmap_area ` and `vm_struct ` for vmalloc

Tags: vmalloc

```
struct vm_struct {
    struct vm_struct    *next;
    void            *addr;
    unsigned long       size;
    unsigned long       flags;
    struct page     **pages;
#ifdef CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_HUGE_VMALLOC
    unsigned int        page_order;
#endif
    unsigned int        nr_pages;
    phys_addr_t     phys_addr;
    const void      *caller;
};

struct vmap_area {
    unsigned long va_start;
    unsigned long va_end;

    struct rb_node rb_node;         /* address sorted rbtree */
    struct list_head list;          /* address sorted list */

    /*
     * The following two variables can be packed, because
     * a vmap_area object can be either:
     *    1) in "free" tree (root is vmap_area_root)
     *    2) or "busy" tree (root is free_vmap_area_root)
     */
    union {
        unsigned long subtree_max_size; /* in "free" tree */
        struct vm_struct *vm;           /* in "busy" tree */
    };
};
```

I have a confusion about this part of the kernel code.

Why do kernel developers use two structures for management?

Why didn't they merge the two structures into one?